# C# Resizing winforms doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a winforms application using [MetroFramework](https://thielj.github.io/MetroFramework/). I want to programmatically resize the form so a larger object can fit on it. For this I'm using a toggle from the framework in a `tabControl` object. Making the form bigger works fine, but when I disable the toggle it doesn't want to shrink the form.

```
private void tSynced_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tSynced.Checked)
    {
        //Sync enabled
        Console.WriteLine("Sync enabled");
        this.Size = new Size(this.Width + 300, this.Height);
        this.MinimumSize = new Size(this.Width, this.Height);
        this.MaximumSize = new Size(this.Width + 200, this.Height);
    } else
    {
        //Sync disabled
        Console.WriteLine("Sync disabled");
        this.Size = new Size(this.Width - 300, this.Height);
        this.Width = 534;
        Console.WriteLine(this.Size);
        this.MinimumSize = new Size(this.Width, this.Height);
        this.MaximumSize = new Size(this.Width, this.Height);
    }
}
```

As you can see I've been experimenting with some techniques that I know, just to give it a try and work my way back from there, but it doesn't seem to work. This seems odd to me, since the first method (the `this.Size` line) does work when making the form bigger. The `this` keyword is referring to the `Form` according to Visual Studio. It doesn't seem to try to resize the `tabControl`, because I bound that to the right side, and properly moves along with the right border.

The log for the `this.Size` will return the large value, which is `{Width=834, Height=354}` in my case.

I've tried saving the initial values in a `Size` variable, and restoring it from there (since it would account for resizing by the user), but that doesn't seem to work correctly.

```
Size oldSize; //Global variable
private void initialize()
{
    oldSize = new Size(this.Width, this.Height);
    Console.WriteLine(oldSize);
}

this.Size = oldSize; //In the eventhandler
```

The log will return the correct value, which is `{Width=534, Height=354}` in my case. But it refuses to use the value when setting the `this.Size` property again...

**What am I overlooking?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When enlarging the form, you set the MinimumSize  to the current size - but when you make it smaller you try to reset the Size while the MinimumSize is still set - so the form doesn't resize.

All you need to do is to reset the MinimumSize before changing the Size.

Comment: Eeewh, herpiederp! I knew it had to be something simple :p Works like a charm! Thank you :)